# Newsletter Form Entry to Database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, database

I have taken the below code from a YouTube tutorial (credit: pbj746). All seems to be working apart from the submitted data not appearing in the database! I have checked the $dbhost, $db, $dbuser and $dbpassword and they all match up but the data is not being pulled in.

If anyone could help that would be great!

```
    <?php
    $dbServer = "localhost";
    $db = "quizsoft_newsletter";
    $dbUser = "admin_newsletter";
    $dbPassword = "password";

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($db);

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO emails ('ID', 'Email')
        VALUES(NULL, '$email')") or die(mysql_error());
    ?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Form</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("div#msgbox").hide();
    $("#addEmail").click(function() {
        $.post('process.php', {
            email:$("#email").val()
        },
        function(response) {
            $("div#msgbox #msg").html("Email Submitted Successfully!")
            $("div#msgbox").slideDown("normal");
        }
        );
        return false;
    });
    $("div#msgbox").click(function() {
        $(this).slideUp("normal");
    })
});
</script>

<style>
body { font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:13px; }
div#msgbox { background:#999; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; color:#FFF; width:100%; height:30px; top:0; left:0; cursor:pointer; }
div#msgbix #msg { line-height:30px; padding-left:10px; }
form#newsletter { margin-top:35px; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="msgbox"><span id="msg"> </span></div>
    <form id="newsletter">
        Email:<input type="text" id="email" />
        <input type="submit" id="addEmail" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks D!

**Edited**: Further more, I have run a simple PHP Script to confirm database connection: http://quizsoft.co.uk/ajaxform/test.php

Comment: `mysql_error()` should tell you what the error is. If there is no error, then you're trying to save blank variables to your database.

Comment: Thanks Debest, no errors appearing with mysql_error(). Would you be able to explain the saving blank variables part - as the inputs have values. Many Thanks!

Comment: try to add `or die(mysql_error());` after both the `mysql_connect` and the `mysql_select_database` function calls just like you do for the `mysql_query`. Also, could you post the table create script?

Answer (score 0):

Besides what's listed below there's also a little syntax error. `$dbServer` should be renamed to `$dbhost` or vice versa.

Also, from your comment I know that you're using auto increment on ID so I suggest you change this

```
INSERT INTO emails ('ID', 'Email') VALUES(NULL, '$email')
```

to this

```
INSERT INTO emails (`Email`) VALUES ('$email')
```

since ID cannot be null and backticks need to be used to encapsulate column names.

Also, just as a heads up, your sql is vulnerable to sql injections and you probably want to look into using pdo (here's a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/)) instead of the deprecated mysql functions. If not, you should at the very least replace

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

by

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the rely @Erik. I have made your suggested changes (really missed those ones). But unfortunately the data is still not being captured. I can only imagine it is how I have set up the database. Although - the table is really simple (ID - INT then auto_increment & email - VARCHA - 40).

Comment: @D.Horton ... See my edit :) also, the sql insert and the html for the form is in separate files right ?

Comment: Still no luck @Erik, must be something I doing wrong. Here are my files and database - would be great to close the thread for future visitors if you could see the issue: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15052360/ajaxform.zip Thanks again!

Comment: @D.Horton see edit, so small I didn't even spot it at first :)